# What are the steps to start Xlet (javax.microedition.xlet) development?

Tags: java, emulation, development-environment, xlet

I've been trying to find a way to play with [Xlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlet) development (as a part of [Personal Basis Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Basis_Profile#Connected_Device_Configuration) in `javax.microedition.xlet` package).

Currently as a starting point I have Eclipse Indigo (I do Android development in it).

My questions are:

- What steps should I do to setup a development environment for Xlets?
- Is there any emulator to run an Xlet on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if my experience helps but at least it provides a reference.
My environment is a linux x86 PC (linux 2.6) + eclipse 3.2 + j2se 1.4.2_09
I downloaded javatv 1.0 / 1.1 source codes of reference implementation from sun.

You can create a project in eclipse where imports all source codes.
Please fix all possible errors (if any). Usually if there are some, just comment them.

Finally, please export the project as a jar file.

You can then create another project and configure the build path, click "import external jars" to import the generated javatv jar.
Now you can create your own xlet by creating a java file which implements javax.tv.Xlet.xlet interface in the same project.

To execute the xlet, you need to implement main method and create
an instance of SIEmulator (assume myemulator). And then you can call
myemulator.putResidentXlet() and fill name / path of the xlet in.
Finally please go to the output folder (which contains the compiled class file of the source codes, usually folder "bin"), type
"java -Djava.class.path="path of the javatv jar" class_containing_main_method

Note that the xlet executed is NOT in a service context. If you wish to run in a service context, you either need to modify codes in com.sun.tv.XletManager.java to fill a service context object for the xlet or put the xlet's info in javatv's SI source, an xml file. Default is "JavaTVSampleFile01.xml". The usage please refer to javatv's documents.

That was from a forum post. LINK: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7310245

Your best chance for file downloads: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/cdc-opt-impl/ojmeec/1.0/reference/html/z4000c841293984.html

Comment: can you provide links to downloads.

Comment: @azulflame: +1, thanks for your reply. However let me admit this is not exactly what I am asking for. The reply is about `javax.tv.xlet` while my question is about `javax.microedition.xlet`.

Comment: Arhimed, I'll be honest (just in case you didn't see the last line): I did not figure that out, I simply found that in a forum post from a link from a google search. The steps should be the same for the microedition as the tv, just using a different jar.

Comment: your last link looks very promising! unfortunately I have no time to try it right now, but it looks like exactly what I've been looking for, so you win. :)